# Replacing Ubuntu 14.04 with Cub Linux, while keeping files

Tags: upgrade

I'd like to install Cub Linux, but I have files that I want to keep on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation. What steps do I need to follow to preserve my files in the process?

Answer (score 0):

Is `/home` on a separate partition? If yes, great! You just need to tell Cub to mount it as `/home` again during installation, without formatting. If not, copy your `/home` directory to another location, and copy it back after installation. I recommend re-doing the partitions to include separate `/` and `/home` partitions when you install Cub if you don't already have it this way.

Comment: Then what about the applications which I had been using? And    /home    directory has not completely copied to another location